Replace number from regexp capture with the output of a command using that number in sed
I want to translate:

"a b c  syscall=257 success=yes"

into the following:

"a b c  syscall=openat success=yes"

I'd like using sed group capturing regexp and replacement combined with the use of the ausyscall applied to the number extracted by the regexp group.
I tried the following under Linux/bash:
echo "a b c  syscall=257 success=yes" |
   sed -e "s:syscall=\([0-9]*\):SYSCALL="$(ausyscall 257)":"

It prints: a b c  SYSCALL=openat success=yes as expected.
Then I tried to use the capture group #1 as the argument to ausyscall. Like this:
echo "a b c  syscall=257 success=yes" | 
   sed -e "s:syscall=\([0-9]*\):SYSCALL="$(ausyscall \1)":"

That invokes ausyscall 1 which prints write. This is not the captured group #1 (which has a value of 257).
So I tried using \\1 instead, but that also fails:
echo "a b c  syscall=257 success=yes" | 
   sed -e "s:syscall=\([0-9]*\):SYSCALL="$(ausyscall \\1)":"

This invokes ausyscall \1 so it fails, prints an error on stderr (Unknown syscall \1 using x86_64 lookup table) and prints a b c  SYSCALL= success=yes on stdout.
It fails passing the captured value to ausyscall.  I tried with single quotes, but then the call to ausyscall is not made.
Is it possible to use sed that way?

I am only interested to know if it's expected to be able to do this with sed.
I know it could be done with other means (perl, python script, gawk, etc), but I want to see if it is possible with sed and if the problem is related to quoting or something like that.

Is it possible with sed?  If so, what am I missing?

GNU sed can do this if you are willing to use the GNU sed e extension to the s command:
$ echo "a b c  syscall=257 success=yes" |
    sed -E "
      h         # copy input line from pattern space to hold space
      s/^.*syscall=([0123456789]+).*$/ausyscall \1/e   # get just the syscall number
      t match   # Conditionally jump to "match" label if above substitution succeeded
      x         #   else revert pattern space back to original input
      b end     #   and jump to "end" label
      :match
      G         # append newline + hold space to pattern space
      s/^([^\n]+)\n(.*syscall=)[0123456789]+(.*)$/\2\1\3/  # replace number with syscall name
      :end
"
a b c  syscall=openat success=yes
$ 

The e extension to s forks a shell and evaluates s's resulting pattern space and replaces the pattern space with the result of the executed command.  In order to mitigate any potential code-injection issues, the regex to extract the syscall number is very careful to only match numeric digits.  [0-9] is not used as it could match other things in various locales.  The resulting number is then passed to a constructed ausyscall command and executed.
The rest of the sed commands are to ensure that if there are input lines that do not contain syscall numbers, then the are left unmodified.

Side note - Ubuntu users may install the ausyscall command by installing the auditd package:
sudo apt install auditd


Note also - whenever you see the word evaluate, take this as a big warning of possible code-injection bugs.  Don't use commands like this on unvetted user input.  Because this case works on strictly numeric data, it is straightforward to validate, but much more care must be taken with more general cases.

I am tempted to mark this as the solution, but now face the security dilemma that Kusalananda was trying to avoid. On the one hand promoting knowledge is good, one the other ensuring that everybody reading it really reads it and understands the potential danger remains.  Perhaps adding a big caution note at the beginning of the port would complement the one that is at the end?

@PRouleau Because the input is effectively validated as numeric-only in this case, I think with the printf version I just added, this should be safe against code-injection attacks.

You are correct, @Digital Trauma,  the data validation is done by extracting the number (and in my original code I was giving context to where the number is located).

One point to highlight is that the beginning of the string of the first echo ends up being processed by the shell if not completely consumed.  So if one would like to ensure that the number extracted is located at the right spot, the regexp would need to include 'syscall=' .  To process lines of audit log and expand the system call # by its name the sed command could be: sed -E "s/^(.+ syscall=)([0-9]+) (.*)$/printf -- '\1%s \3' \$(ausyscall \2)/e". The -- in the printf handles a line taht starts with a dash.

Even your Update is highly unsafe. Single quoting doesn't help if the input may contain single quotes, %s are a problem for printf format. Beware [0-9] may match many characters besides 0123456789 depending on the locale. That e flag should really never be used.

Much better now after your edit, though you'd want to add a \n. Note that the actual output of ausearch (which this is obviously about here) will have other digits before syscall=257 (a b c are just place holders), so the pattern would have to be amended.

@StéphaneChazelas I refactored it more to remove the unnecessary printf dependency.  Now the only command that can get is evaled is ausyscall <digit-string>

Beware that if there's POSIXLY_CORRECT=something in the environment, [^\n] matches on characters other than backslash and n. You can just use s/^(.*)\n.../.../ here, since there will be only one newline.

a b c are placeholders for 3 space separated words (type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1730485493.366:1135): arch=c000003e for instance), so you could match on ^\S+ \S+ \S+ syscall=... to avoid matching another potential occurrence of syscall= on the line. Using LC_ALL=C would avoid text decoding issue (possibly not possible with ausearch output though) and let you use [0-9] safely. Also note the T command of GNU sed which would simplify your branching.

"with the result of the executed command" should probably be "with the standard output of the executed command stripped of up to one trailing newline character"


I am only interested to know if it's expected to be able to do this with sed.

It's not expected that sed can do this. It can't! The actual running of the command is something that your shell does, not sed, so this is not a feature of sed, but another program, the shell

I know it could be done with other means (perl, python script, gawk, etc),

You're already approaching it that way! You're using a script language interpreter as replacement engine, and within that, are using sed to do a few elementary operations. Your shell (be it bash, ash, zsh, csh, cmd, …) is no different than, say, the python interpreter.

That's correct, I'm using the shell command invocation. And you answered my question.  the combination of sed in the shell can't seem to do what I tried to do. I'll wait a little and will most probably accept your answer.

I don't think sed can do this, but perl can and is only slightly more complex:
echo "a b c  syscall=257 success=yes" |
  perl -pe 's:syscall=(\d+):"SYSCALL=" . `ausyscall $1`:e'

Although, that will most likely add an extra newline there which you don't want. So you might need this instead:
echo "a b c  syscall=257 success=yes" |
  perl -pe 's:syscall=(\d+):chomp($v=`ausyscall $1`); "SYSCALL=$v" :e'

Perl's s operator works pretty much the same way as sed's. The only difference here is that by using the e flag at the end (s:old:new:e), that allows us to run perl code in the replacement side, and use the result of the code. The code in question is:

`ausyscall $1`: run ausyscall passing it $1 (this is the equivalent to sed's \1—although Perl can also work with \1, just not with the e flag—so it's whatever was captured by the first set of parentheses) as an argument. Note that the command is run in the default shell of the system (usually sh).

chomp($v=`...`): remove trailing newlines. This removes the newline returned by the ausyscall command.  The result is stored in the variable $v.

"SYSCALL=$v": this returns the desired output.


Note that this is a risky approach. It is fine here, in this specific case, since you are explicitly only capturing numerical digits, but as a general rule, you don't want to execute arbitrary input as a command as that makes you vulnerable to a code injection attack.

GNU sed does this with the /e substitution flag, but it opens up a can of security issues that makes me wonder whether mentioning it is worthwhile.

@Kusalananda, for the purpose of fully understanding sed capabilities and limitation as well as the security issues, I think it would be worthwhile if the security issues are described.

Thanks @terdon for showing how it can be done in Perl; a good reference.

@PRouleau the security issue is simply the existence of an operation that lets you execute arbitrary code based on what comes in via some string. I'd just generally call it "a bad idea" to take strings from data that the user is parsing (often in an ad-hoc manner) and execute commands "as if you were a shell". Example: you have something like ausyscall {placeholder}, and when you use /e, it gets executed, by passing the string to system(). That sounds all fine, and in your case you only pass in numbers, but in a slightly different

scenario, where these placeholders are, say, kid's names, and one of the kids entered into the system was entered as James; rsync --ignore-errors -r / someserver.com:unauthorized_backups/, you suddenly have a problem.

(GNU sed on my machine uses popen(), not system(), which makes sense and has the same security "problem" of being totally insecure)

@MarcusMüller I agree completely that non-validated data being processed by the shell as argument is a security issue.  But what interest me is to see how you could use the /e option here in sed to handle this problem.  The descriptions above contain the info for the security side, thanks for spelling it out.  I just don't see (yet) how the /e does anything to help resolve the problem I described originally.

Re: edit reversed. Fair enough. I was also wrong in saying it runs sh as in this particular case, since there's no special shell operators other than space as argument delimiter, perl skips running sh. In the general case, it may run sh, so your trailing warning is welcome and spot on.

In any case, that answer is much better than the currently accepted one using sed's infamous e flag and nowhere as unsafe.

Huh, thanks, @StéphaneChazelas I also thought it weould always run a shell. By the way, one of the things in your edit which I removed (didn't roll back, I kept your improvements to the code, I only removed part of the explanation), mentioned the shell ... operator. I have been using ... as an alias to cd ../../ for years on my systems, is there really a shell operator ... as well?

That was referring to the backtick operator, not ...

You could easily use sed to translate the input line into a shell command that would then be able to produce the desired output.  The shell's eval command, combined with command substitution, should do the trick to process one line at a time, as in your example.  Say, something like this:
echo "a b c  syscall=257 success=yes" | \
  eval $(sed -e 's/^/echo "/' \
             -e 's/syscall=\([0-9]*\)/syscall=$(ausyscall \1)/' \
             -e 's/$/"/')

However as others have answered, given the specifics of your application, and depending on how many times you need to do this (i.e. how many lines of input you want to process at any given time), using ausyscall is probably the least efficient and effective way to do it.

Thanks Greg.  This provides more info on sed, which was my intent for the questions.  On real code, I would probably pre-load an array with the output of ausyscall --dump and use that array as a look-up table.  That would be much faster.   My question was written to get more info on what sed can do in that type of scenario and you gave an interesting related answer.


I want to translate:

"a b c  syscall=257 success=yes"

into the following:

"a b c  syscall=openat success=yes"


That's what the -i option of ausearch does (and more):

-i, --interpret
Interpret numeric entities into text. For example, uid is converted to account name. If the audit logs are unenriched, the conversion is done using the current resources of the
machine  where the search is being run. If you have renamed the accounts, or don't have the same accounts on your machine, you could get misleading results. If the logs are enriched, it uses the supplemental data to do the conversion. This allows accurate log reporting even when run on a different machine than the original logs came from.

$ sudo ausearch -k a
time->Fri Nov  1 11:28:13 2024
type=PROCTITLE msg=audit(1730460493.172:119): proctitle=6361740061
type=PATH msg=audit(1730460493.172:119): item=0 name="a" inode=5504724 dev=00:2b mode=0100775 ouid=1000 ogid=1000 rdev=00:00 nametype=NORMAL cap_fp=0 cap_fi=0 cap_fe=0 cap_fver=0 cap_frootid=0
type=CWD msg=audit(1730460493.172:119): cwd="/home/chazelas"
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1730460493.172:119): arch=c000003e syscall=257 success=yes exit=3 a0=ffffff9c a1=7ffe02333e53 a2=0 a3=0 items=1 ppid=15215 pid=23968 auid=1000 uid=1000 gid=1000 euid=1000 suid=1000 fsuid=1000 egid=1000 sgid=1000 fsgid=1000 tty=pts2 ses=3 comm="cat" exe="/usr/bin/cat" subj=unconfined key="a"

$ sudo ausearch -k a -i
type=PROCTITLE msg=audit(01/11/24 11:28:13.172:119) : proctitle=cat a
type=PATH msg=audit(01/11/24 11:28:13.172:119) : item=0 name=a inode=5504724 dev=00:2b mode=file,775 ouid=chazelas ogid=chazelas rdev=00:00 nametype=NORMAL cap_fp=none cap_fi=none cap_fe=0 cap_fver=0 cap_frootid=0
type=CWD msg=audit(01/11/24 11:28:13.172:119) : cwd=/home/chazelas
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(01/11/24 11:28:13.172:119) : arch=x86_64 syscall=openat success=yes exit=3 a0=AT_FDCWD a1=0x7ffe02333e53 a2=O_RDONLY a3=0x0 items=1 ppid=15215 pid=23968 auid=chazelas uid=chazelas gid=chazelas euid=chazelas suid=chazelas fsuid=chazelas egid=chazelas sgid=chazelas fsgid=chazelas tty=pts2 ses=3 comm=cat exe=/usr/bin/cat subj=unconfined key=a

See how the syscall number was translated, but also the timestamp¹, arch, mode, uids, gids, some arguments to the syscall...
Running ausyscall for every occurrence of syscall=<numbers> in the input would be very inefficient, especially considering that both GNU sed and perl as used in some other answers also run or may run a shell to interpret the command. GNU sed's e command and e flag of the s command is also virtually impossible to use safely, I would highly recommend against using it, ever.
Here, if you only wanted to translate the syscall numbers and not the other ids as ausearch does, best would be do use the output of ausyscall --dump (run once) that gives you the full mapping:
sudo ausearch... | perl -pe '
  BEGIN {%map = split " ", qx{ausyscall --dump}}
  s/^type=SYSCALL.*? syscall=\K\d+/$map{$&}/'

That assumes you're on a single architecture system, as syscall numbers are architecture-dependant. For instance, on a modern PC where you can have applications running in x86 or amd64 (aka x86_64) mode, that will not work properly if there are system calls made by x86 applications as ausyscall gives you the translations for amd64 syscalls.
ausearch -i does it correctly, but to do the same, you'd need to construct two maps, one for x86 and one for amd64 and extract the architecture from the audit record.
Example, using a static build of x86 busybox here:
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1730460493.172:119): arch=c000003e syscall=257 success=yes exit=3 a0=ffffff9c a1=7ffe02333e53 a2=0 a3=0 items=1 ppid=15215 pid=23968 auid=1000 uid=1000 gid=1000 euid=1000 suid=1000 fsuid=1000 egid=1000 sgid=1000 fsgid=1000 tty=pts2 ses=3 comm="cat" exe="/usr/bin/cat" subj=unconfined key="a"
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1730462981.012:250): arch=40000003 syscall=295 success=yes exit=3 a0=ffffff9c a1=ffdcce69 a2=8000 a3=0 items=1 ppid=27309 pid=27411 auid=1000 uid=1000 gid=1000 euid=1000 suid=1000 fsuid=1000 egid=1000 sgid=1000 fsgid=1000 tty=pts11 ses=3 comm="busybox-x86" exe="/home/chazelas/busybox-x86" subj=unconfined key="a"

Those are 2 openat system calls, the first one being the amd64 one by cat, the second the x86 one by busybox-x86.
ausearch -i translates it properly:
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(01/11/24 11:28:13.172:119) : arch=x86_64 syscall=openat success=yes exit=3 a0=AT_FDCWD a1=0x7ffe02333e53 a2=O_RDONLY a3=0x0 items=1 ppid=15215 pid=23968 auid=chazelas uid=chazelas gid=chazelas euid=chazelas suid=chazelas fsuid=chazelas egid=chazelas sgid=chazelas fsgid=chazelas tty=pts2 ses=3 comm=cat exe=/usr/bin/cat subj=unconfined key=a
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(01/11/24 12:09:41.012:250) : arch=i386 syscall=openat success=yes exit=3 a0=AT_FDCWD a1=0xffdcce69 a2=O_RDONLY a3=0x0 items=1 ppid=27309 pid=27411 auid=chazelas uid=chazelas gid=chazelas euid=chazelas suid=chazelas fsuid=chazelas egid=chazelas sgid=chazelas fsgid=chazelas tty=pts11 ses=3 comm=busybox-x86 exe=/home/chazelas/busybox-x86 subj=unconfined key=a

But the perl code above gets it wrong (and so would your attempt):
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1730460493.172:119): arch=c000003e syscall=openat success=yes exit=3 a0=ffffff9c a1=7ffe02333e53 a2=0 a3=0 items=1 ppid=15215 pid=23968 auid=1000 uid=1000 gid=1000 euid=1000 suid=1000 fsuid=1000 egid=1000 sgid=1000 fsgid=1000 tty=pts2 ses=3 comm="cat" exe="/usr/bin/cat" subj=unconfined key="a"
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1730462981.012:250): arch=40000003 syscall=preadv success=yes exit=3 a0=ffffff9c a1=ffdcce69 a2=8000 a3=0 items=1 ppid=27309 pid=27411 auid=1000 uid=1000 gid=1000 euid=1000 suid=1000 fsuid=1000 egid=1000 sgid=1000 fsgid=1000 tty=pts11 ses=3 comm="busybox-x86" exe="/home/chazelas/busybox-x86" subj=unconfined key="a"

As 295 is the number of the preadv amd64 syscall, and that of the openat x86 syscall.
So on that multi-arch system, I'd need something like:
sudo ausearch... | perl -pe '
  BEGIN {
    %{$map{"c000003e"}} = split " ", qx{ausyscall --dump b64};
    %{$map{"40000003"}} = split " ", qx{ausyscall --dump b32};
  }
  s/^type=SYSCALL.*? arch=(\S+) syscall=\K\d+/$map{$1}->{$&}/'

Which correctly gives me:
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1730460493.172:119): arch=c000003e syscall=openat success=yes exit=3 a0=ffffff9c a1=7ffe02333e53 a2=0 a3=0 items=1 ppid=15215 pid=23968 auid=1000 uid=1000 gid=1000 euid=1000 suid=1000 fsuid=1000 egid=1000 sgid=1000 fsgid=1000 tty=pts2 ses=3 comm="cat" exe="/usr/bin/cat" subj=unconfined key="a"
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1730462981.012:250): arch=40000003 syscall=openat success=yes exit=3 a0=ffffff9c a1=ffdcce69 a2=8000 a3=0 items=1 ppid=27309 pid=27411 auid=1000 uid=1000 gid=1000 euid=1000 suid=1000 fsuid=1000 egid=1000 sgid=1000 fsgid=1000 tty=pts11 ses=3 comm="busybox-x86" exe="/home/chazelas/busybox-x86" subj=unconfined key="a"

If ausyscall didn't support --dump, you could at least cache the result to avoid having to run it several times for the same value:
sudo ausearch... | perl -pe '
  BEGIN {%arch = qw(c000003e b64 40000003 b32)}
  s{^type=SYSCALL.*? arch=(\d+) syscall=\K\d+}{
    $cache{$1}->{$&} //= eval {
      $name = `ausyscall $arch{$1} $&`;
      chomp $name;
      $name;
    }
  }e'

(here also handling amd64 and x86 architectures).

¹ using local time (use TZ=UTC0 for UTC time) and formatted as strftime("%x %T"), locale-dependant; use a locale such as csb_PL de_AT de_BE de_LU en_CA en_DK eo fr_CA hu_HU kv_RU lt_LT se_NO si_LK sv_SE wae_CH to get a less ambiguous ISO8601-like timestamp: sudo TZ=UTC0 LC_ALL= LC_TIME=en_DK.UTF-8 ausearch -i ...; make sure that locale is available on your system, otherwise you'll get US-style timestamps from the C locale in %m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S format.
